# help with creating linux shell using C

Tags: c, linux

I'm supposed to create a linux shell using C. Below is my code:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define SHELL "/bin/sh"
#include "extern.h"

int mysystem (char *command)
{
  int status;
  pid_t pid;

  pid = fork ();
  if (pid == 0)
    {

      execl (SHELL, SHELL, "-c", command, NULL);
      _exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  else if (pid < 0)

    status = -1;
  else

    if (waitpid (pid, &status, 0) != pid)
      status = -1;
  return status;
}
```

Everything is right when I test the code using different commands like "ls", "man", etc. but when I use notepad to create a testfile containing the following:

```
echo "hello"
exit 2
```

the return code come out to be `512` when it's supposed to be just `2`.
Can anyone help me fix my code?

Comment: can anyone help me edit my question. there are things missing. thx

Comment: Does it work when you put a semicolon after echo "hello" ?

Comment: @Amir Afghani: no, it doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

`status` is not the exit code; it contains other information as well. Normally the return value is in bits 8-15 of `status`, but you should be using the macros in `wait.h` to extract the return value from `status` in a portable way.

Note that 512 is `2<<8`.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you're using the macros like `WIFEXITED` and `WEXITSTATUS` on your `status` value.  See your operating system's man page for `waitpid`.  [Here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/waitpid.html) is a description of the POSIX requirements on `waitpid`.

Answer (score 0):

By notepad do you mean you're using a Windows program to create a Unix shell script?  That doesn't work because you end up with CRLF at the end of each line instead of LF.  Try the "dos2unix" command on the script to convert it to Unix format and then run it.

I assume you're aware that code is already available in the system() library call?  Judging by your function name, I'd guess you're just trying to learn how to do it with system calls.

Comment: what do u mean that the code is already available in the system()library call? can you show me?

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing your `command` string you supply to `/bin/sh` with quotes, because otherwise the space character makes `/bin/sh` think you are supplying another option to the shell itself, not to the command you are calling. For example, try this in a terminal:

```
/bin/sh -c exit 2
echo $?
```

and

```
/bin/sh -c "exit 2"
echo $?
```

The first one gives `0`, and the second one gives the desired `2`.

Comment: but when I do ./mysystem in the terminal, it still prints out 512.

Comment: It prints 512 because you don't use the WEXITSTATUS macro, as others have noted. Try changing the last line of your function to be `return WEXITSTATUS(status)`.